# How to build Prisma Windows electron app on Linux?

Tags: npm, prisma, electron-builder

What we want to achieve is to build linux and windows installers for our Electron app on our (Linux) build server.

After installing Wine, this basically works, except for Prisma:

i.e. Prisma relies on OS-specific binaries - thus, we must have the correct binaries available for each platform.

### Prisma Query engine / Prisma Client

This part works: we set the [binaryTarget](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/generators#the-native-binary-target) to our target platforms: `binaryTargets = ["windows", "debian-openssl-1.1.x"]`.
When we now generate the client (`prisma generate`), the target dir (`node_modules/.prisma/client/`) contains the query-engines for linux and windows: `libquery_engine-debian-openssl-1.1.x.so.node`, `query_engine-windows.dll.node`

### Prisma Migration Engine

i.e. in `package.json` we only specify the `prisma` dependency and npm will only install the binaries for the current OS in `node_modules/@prisma/engines/`, i.e.: `libquery_engine-debian-openssl-1.1.x.so.node`, `migration-engine-debian-openssl-1.1.x`

How can we get npm to install both migration Engines (i.e. for Windows and Linux)?

Comment: [Reference to GitHub Discussion](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/discussions/14092)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- set the [PRISMA_CLI_BINARY_TARGETS](https://www.prisma.io/docs/reference/api-reference/environment-variables-reference#cli-binary-targets) accordingly: e.g. `PRISMA_CLI_BINARY_TARGETS=darwin,rhel-openssl-1.0.x npm install`
- then start `npm install`
- and now the binaries for all specified operating systems should exist in `node_modules/@prisma/engines`

  - in my case, this did not work initially
  - after deleting `node_modules/@prisma/engines` and starting `npm install` again, it worked